# Print multiple entries from a JSON response to e GET Request

Tags: python, json

This is my first post and I am new to python. I have been fooling round with the deck of cards API. I am trying to do a rudimentary script where I print the three cards I draw from the deck. I can only get it to print the last card 2 times. I am trying to print the three different "value" and "suit". See JSON output from my GET request:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "deck_id": "jj1qy9tz9fkj",
    "cards": [
        {
            "code": "2H",
            "image": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/2H.png",
            "images": {
                "svg": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/2H.svg",
                "png": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/2H.png"
            },
            "value": "2",
            "suit": "HEARTS"
        },
        {
            "code": "KC",
            "image": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/KC.png",
            "images": {
                "svg": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/KC.svg",
                "png": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/KC.png"
            },
            "value": "KING",
            "suit": "CLUBS"
        },
        {
            "code": "QH",
            "image": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/QH.png",
            "images": {
                "svg": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/QH.svg",
                "png": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/QH.png"
            },
            "value": "QUEEN",
            "suit": "HEARTS"
        }
    ],
    "remaining": 49
}
```

Here is my script:

```
import requests


url = "https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/shuffle/?deck_count=1"

payload = {}
headers = {
  'Cookie': '__cfduid=xxxxxxxxxxx; Cookie_1=value'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text)
deck = response.json()
deck_id = deck['deck_id']
print(deck_id)

url = "https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/" + deck_id + "/draw/?count=3"



response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text)
response_data = response.json()
for element in response_data['cards']:
    card1 = element['value']
    suit1 = element['suit']
for element in response_data['cards']:
    card2 = element['value']
    suit2 = element['suit']
for element in response_data['cards']:
    card3 = element['value']
    suit3 = element['suit']
print(str(card1) + ' of ' + str(suit1))
print(str(card2) + ' of ' + str(suit2))
print(str(card3) + ' of ' + str(suit3))
remaining = response.json()
card_remaining = remaining['remaining']
print('There are ' + str(card_remaining) + ' cards remaining')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you were going with here, but I guess you stated you're new to python:

```
for element in response_data['cards']:
    card1 = element['value']
    suit1 = element['suit']
for element in response_data['cards']:
    card2 = element['value']
    suit2 = element['suit']
for element in response_data['cards']:
    card3 = element['value']
    suit3 = element['suit']
print(str(card1) + ' of ' + str(suit1))
print(str(card2) + ' of ' + str(suit2))
print(str(card3) + ' of ' + str(suit3))
remaining = response.json()
card_remaining = remaining['remaining']
```

You should scratch the aforementioned lines and replace them with just this:

```
for element in response_data['cards']:
    print(element['value'] + ' of ' + element['suit'])
card_remaining = response_data['remaining']
```

Comment: That fixed my problem. Thanks much for helping.

Answer (score 0):

It's a list of dictionaries. You can just iterate through it and pull the elements you need.

```
data ={
"success": True,
"deck_id": "jj1qy9tz9fkj",
"cards": [
    {
        "code": "2H",
        "image": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/2H.png",
        "images": {
            "svg": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/2H.svg",
            "png": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/2H.png"
        },
        "value": "2",
        "suit": "HEARTS"
    },
    {
        "code": "KC",
        "image": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/KC.png",
        "images": {
            "svg": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/KC.svg",
            "png": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/KC.png"
        },
        "value": "KING",
        "suit": "CLUBS"
    },
    {
        "code": "QH",
        "image": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/QH.png",
        "images": {
            "svg": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/QH.svg",
            "png": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/QH.png"
        },
        "value": "QUEEN",
        "suit": "HEARTS"
    }
],
"remaining": 49
}

# iterate through your list
for el in data.get('cards'):
    print('value: ', el.get('value'))
    print('suit: ', el.get('suit'),'\n')
```

Output:

```
value:  2
suit:  HEARTS

value:  KING
suit:  CLUBS

value:  QUEEN
suit:  HEARTS
```

Answer (score 0):

**Shortest Method**

```py
cards = response_data['cards']

[print(f"{card['value']} of {card['suit']}") for card in cards]

print(f"There are {response_data['remaining']} cards remaining.")
```

Using python's [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), we can do this in a more cleaner way.